# pg_dump without comments on objects?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Is there a way to perform a pg_dump and exclude the COMMENT ON for tables/views and columns ?

I use extensively the COMMENT ON command to describe all objects, and often include newlines in them for clearer descriptions, e.g.:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE mytable1 IS 'MAIN TABLE...
NOTES:
1. ...
2. ...
3. ...
';
```

However, since there are newlines in the dump as well, I cannot simply remove the comments with a grep -v 'COMMENT ON' command.

Any other way to quickly remove these COMMENT ON from the dump ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with `pg_dump`

Comment: Possible solution - restore dump, find all coments and drop them, create new dump. You can find and drop all coments with dynamic SQL and metadata query.

Comment: A smarter `sed` or `perl` script could do this, since the grammar of `COMMENT ON` is pretty simple. All you'd need to do is make sure you got the string escape parsing correct, ignoring doubled quotes for cases like `COMMENT ON ... 'It''s alright';`

Answer (score 5):

Use the `--no-comments` option.

Example:

```
$ pg_dump --no-comments [database] > dump.sql
```

References: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, neither `pg_dump` nor `pg_restore` have options to remove `COMMENT`s. But, if you use a binary dump format like:

```
 $ pg_dump -Fc <your connection> -f /path/to/backup.dump
```

you could extract the TOC entry and edit it:

```
 $ pg_restore -l -f /path/to/backup.toc /path/to/backup.dump
```

The above will extract a TOC file and save it at `/path/to/backup.toc`, then you could find each line with `COMMENT` entry and remove or comment it. If you don't use strange names on your objects, a simple `sed` would solve the problem, to comment the lines with `COMMENT`s you could do this (a semicolon starts a comment):

```
$ sed -i 's/^\(.* COMMENT .*\)/;\1/g' bar.toc
```

With this new TOC file, you can now use `pg_restore` to restore your dump (with `-L` option):

```
$ pg_restore -L /path/to/backup.toc -d <your database> /path/to/backup.dump
```

Comment: This creating TOC and restoring with modified TOC was a really nice solution! Thanks! Didn't even need to use `sed` since TOC was modifiable via my editor

Answer (score 2):

I would actually do this with a two-stage dump and restore.

1. Dump and restore the db as is or create a new db from the old one with `createdb -T` or `CREATE DATABASE WITH TEMPLATE`
2. Run the following command

   ```
   Delete from pg_description;
   ```
3. Dump and restore that database.  That will ensure you don't have any annoying dependencies floating around.