# Removing COMMENT ON from all objects in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ddl

In the same vein as [pg_dump without comments on objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027611/pg-dump-without-comments-on-objects), is anyone aware of a command to quickly get rid of the comments (created with `COMMENT ON`) on all objects at once ?

For now, I resorted to bash generating a SQL script that would void one by one the comments on each table/view/column, but it is quite slow, especially with >4000 columns.
Example:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN table1.column1 IS NULL;
COMMENT ON COLUMN table1.column2 IS NULL;
COMMENT ON COLUMN table1.column3 IS NULL;
...
```

Comment: Try writing a PL/SQL function, that queries `pg_description` and deletes coments with dynamic SQL. It will be much faster than any bash  script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have faced a very similar problem some time ago and came up with a very simple solution: delete from the system catalog table [`pg_description`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-description.html) **directly**. Comments are just "attached" to objects and don't interfere otherwise.

```
DELETE FROM pg_description WHERE description = 'something special';
```

Disclaimer:
Manipulating catalog tables directly is **dangerous** and a measure of last resort. You have to *know what you are doing* and you are doing it at your own risk! If you screw up, you may screw up your database (cluster).

I asked about the idea on pgsql-admin list and got an [encouraging answer from Tom Lane](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1237.1303528918%40sss.pgh.pa.us):

```
> DELETE FROM pg_description WHERE description = 'My very special
> totally useless comment.';

> AFAICS, there are no side-effects. Are there any?

It's safe enough, as long as you don't delete the wrong comments.
There's no hidden infrastructure for a comment.

            regards, tom lane
```

You should make sure that there aren't any comments you'd rather keep.
Inspect what your are going to delete first. Be aware that many built-in Postgres objects have comments, too.

For instance, to only **delete all comments on table columns**, you could use:

```
SELECT *
-- DELETE
FROM   pg_description
WHERE  objsubid > 0;
```

[The manual informs about the column `objsubid`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-description.html)

> For a comment on a table column, this is the column number (the `objoid` and
> `classoid` refer to the table itself). For all other object types, this column is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thanks to your help, I found the following commands pretty useful:

To delete a comment from a given column position of a specific object (here, mytable), you could go:

```
DELETE FROM pg_description WHERE (SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid=objoid)='mytable' AND objsubid=2;
```

...but note that it's not more efficient than using COMMENT ON mytable.myfield IS NULL;

Now, to delete all comments from my user-defined views and underlying columns, here's what works very well:

```
DELETE FROM pg_description WHERE (SELECT relkind FROM pg_class WHERE oid=objoid)='v' AND (SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid=objoid) ~ 'v_';
```

where:

- (SELECT relkind FROM pg_class WHERE oid=objoid)='v': all views
- (SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid=objoid) ~ 'v_' : additional security, my views' names all start with 'v_'

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this without hacking a system table, then this will generate the statements for you:

```
SELECT 'COMMENT ON COLUMN ' || quote_ident(pg_namespace.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(pg_class.relname) || '.' || quote_ident(columns.column_name) || ' IS NULL;'
FROM   pg_description
JOIN pg_class ON pg_class.oid = pg_description.objoid
JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
JOIN information_schema.columns 
  ON columns.table_schema = pg_namespace.nspname
 AND columns.table_name = pg_class.relname
 AND columns.ordinal_position = pg_description.objsubid
```

You should probably add a WHERE clause that constrains it to your schemas.